# copy file from one location to another using javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

After a user chooses files from upload default button, I want to copy all selected files to another directory. Is it possible to do so using javascript?
Examples will be very helpful :) !

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The question is formulated incredibly unclear. Please add details concerning: Where the files are moved, What you mean by "default upload button" for starters.

Comment: If your talking about server side JS, like Node, then yes it is possible. Try something like this:
```fs.createReadStream('path/to/file.js').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('new/path/to/file.js'));```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not.

(Client-side) JavaScript does not have access to the file system.

Comment: So, what's with the -1? This _does_ answer the question...

Comment: I didn't push the "-1" button. not me. Thanks for your answer!